# Polymorphism - Appropriate usage of a pointer to a pure abstract class?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, abstract-class

I am implementing a simple board game (Breakthrough) using OpenGL (plus GLUT and GLUI).

I'm thinking of implementing a `Board` class, which will have a `vector<vector<Cell> >` as one of its attributes. `Cell` represents a space in the game board. It can contain a `GameObject`. `GameObject` will be a pure abstract class. It mandates that its derivative classes implement `render()`, for example. Possible derivative classes will be:

- `Blank`, representing an empty space
- `Pawn`, representing a pawn (the only possible pieces in Breakthrough)

The board will be rendered by first rendering the board, then iterating through each `Cell`, getting its contents and calling `render()` for each of them.

The only possible way I can think of to achieving this is making the `GameObject` in `Cell` a pointer (`board[y][x].getContents()->render()`, where `getContents()` returns the `GameObject*`)

Is this the best way to do this? Is this an appropriate usage of pointers?

Comment: A `pointer to a pure abstract class` is never ok. It is also not normally possible. However, you can have a `pointer of type (abstract_class*) pointing to a non-abstract instance of a derived one, yes.

Comment: @sehe - you got what I meant. `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me promote my comment into an answer. This doesn't mean that it's in any sense complete, only that this allows me to spell out some code examples. My original comment:

> That's OK, though you probably would do better with a `std::unique_ptr<GameObject>` or a `std::shared_ptr<GameObject>` so you don't get lost amids the manual lifetime management issues. Finally, how about a flat 1-D array accessible in strides?

Here's how I might go about this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct GameObject { virtual void render() const = 0; virtual ~GameObject() { } };

class Cell
{
  std::unique_ptr<GameObject> m_go;

public:
  void render() const { m_go->render(); }
  Cell() : m_go(new BlankCell) { }
  // more functions to reassign the cell value etc.
};

class Board
{
  std::vector<Cell> m_board;
  std::size_t       m_length;

public:
  Board(std::size_t length) : m_board(length * length), m_length(length) { }
  Cell & cell(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) { return m_board(j + i * m_length); }
  Cell const & cell(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const { return const_cast<Board*>(this)->cell(i, j); }
  // more...
}
```

Comment: `board[y][x].getContents()` is correct, yes. Let me correct that.

Comment: @FranciscoP.: Cool, I removed that sentence since it has no further purpose.

Comment: About the flat 1D array + strides: The boards will be fed to this C++ application via a socket interface to a Prolog based program. The Prolog program uses a `list` of `list`s to represent the content, so I thought I'd keep it consistent. That's the only reason and it's not a particularly strong one :P

Comment: @FranciscoP.: If you're making copies of the ranges at the call site anyway, you could just construct the requisite output container as needed. You'd have to copy the vectors into lists anyway...

Comment: C++ app feeds prolog app moves, prolog app feeds C++ the resulting board from that move.

Comment: On the inter-engine communication: there is a standard that you might want to use (http://home.hccnet.nl/h.g.muller/engine-intf.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Also, maybe you should use another container for your cells (some kind of matrices or so)